# Footer in excel gets distorted when exported to excel from SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export-to-excel

SSRS report when Exporting to Excel the footer format is distorted.(See below image)[image]

Any suggestions.

Comment: Have anyone faced this kind of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by using place holders(HTML) Option and used a single text box for first three strings.